# Octave: invalid call to a script

Tags: octave

I am trying to call to a script, and I am getting an error message. Please help.

The following is what I am trying to run in Octave:

```
%%% May 23, 2016
%%% Potential Fields for Robot Path Planning
%
%
% Initially proposed for real-time collision avoidance [Khatib 1986].  
% Hundreds of papers published on APF
% A potential field is a scalar function over the free space.
% To navigate, the robot applies a force proportional to the 
% negated gradient of the potential field.
% A navigation function is an ideal potential field 

clc
close all
clear 
%% Defining environment variables
startPos = [5,5];
goalPos = [90, 95];
obs1Pos = [50, 50];
obsRad = 10;
goalR = 0.2; % The radius of the goal
goalS = 20;  % The spread of attraction of the goal
obsS = 30;   % The spread of repulsion of the obstacle
alpha = 0.8; % Strength of attraction
beta = 0.6;  % Strength of repulsion


%% Carry out the Potential Field Math as follows: 

u = zeros(100, 100);
v = zeros(100, 100);
testu = zeros(100, 100);
testv = zeros(100, 100);


for x = 1:1:100
    for y = 1:1:100
        [uG, vG] = GoalDelta(x, y, goalPos(1), goalPos(2), goalR, goalS, alpha);
        [uO, vO] = ObsDelta(x, y, obs1Pos(2), obs1Pos(1), obsRad, obsS, beta);
        xnet = uG + uO;
        ynet = vG + vO;
        vspeed = sqrt(xnet^2 + ynet^2);
        theta = atan2(ynet,xnet);
        u(x,y) = vspeed*cos(theta);
        v(x,y) = vspeed*sin(theta);
%         hold on
        
    end
end
%%
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1:100,1:1:100);
figure
quiver(X, Y, u, v, 3)


%% Defining the grid

% Plotting the obstacles
circles(obs1Pos(1),obs1Pos(2),obsRad, 'facecolor','red')
axis square

hold on % Plotting start position
circles(startPos(1),startPos(2),2, 'facecolor','green')

hold on % Plotting goal position
circles(goalPos(1),goalPos(2),2, 'facecolor','yellow')

%% Priting of the path
currentPos = startPos;
x = 0;

while sqrt((goalPos(1)-currentPos(1))^2 + (goalPos(2)-currentPos(2))^2) > 1
    tempPos = currentPos + [u(currentPos(1),currentPos(2)), v(currentPos(1),currentPos(2))]
    currentPos = round(tempPos)
    hold on
    plot(currentPos(1),currentPos(2),'-o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'black')
    pause(0.5)
end
```

The following is the error message I am getting:

```
error: invalid call to script C:\Users\MyComputer\Downloads\circles.m
error: called from
    circles
    ECE8743_PotentialFields_Obstacle_1 at line 59 column 1
>>
```

Here is circles.m:

```
function [ h ] = circles(x,y,r,varargin)
% h = circles(x,y,r,varargin) plots circles of radius r at points x and y. 
% x, y, and r can be scalars or N-D arrays.  
% 
% Chad Greene, March 2014. Updated August 2014. 
% University of Texas Institute for Geophysics. 
% 
%% Syntax 
%  circles(x,y,r)
%  circles(...,'points',numberOfPoints)
%  circles(...,'rotation',degreesRotation)
%  circles(...,'ColorProperty',ColorValue)
%  circles(...,'LineProperty',LineValue)
%  h = circles(...)
% 
%% Description
% 
% circles(x,y,r) plots circle(s) of radius or radii r centered at points given by 
% x and y.  Inputs x, y, and r may be any combination of scalar,
% vector, or 2D matrix, but dimensions of all nonscalar inputs must agree. 
% 
% circles(...,'points',numberOfPoints) allows specification of how many points to use 
% for the outline of each circle. Default value is 1000, but this may be
% increased to increase plotting resolution.  Or you may specify a small
% number (e.g. 4 to plot a square, 5 to plot a pentagon, etc.). 
% 
% circles(...,'rotation',degreesRotation) rotates the shape by a given
% degreesRotation, which can be a scalar or a matrix. This is useless for
% circles, but may be desired for polygons with a discernible number of corner points. 
% 
% circles(...,'ColorProperty',ColorValue) allows declaration of
% 'facecolor' or 'facealpha'
% as name-value pairs. Try declaring any fill property as name-value pairs. 
%
% circles(...,'LineProperty',LineValue) allows declaration of 'edgecolor', 
% 'linewidth', etc.
%
% h = circles(...) returns the handle(s) h of the plotted object(s). 
% 
% 
%% EXAMPLES: 
%
% Example 1: 
% circles(5,10,3)
% 
% % Example 2: 
% x = 2:7;
% y = [5,15,12,25,3,18]; 
% r = [3 4 5 5 7 3]; 
% figure
% circles(x,y,r)
% 
% % Example 3: 
% figure
% circles(1:10,5,2)
% 
% % Example 4: 
% figure
% circles(5,15,1:5,'facecolor','none')
% 
% % Example 5: 
% figure 
% circles(5,10,3,'facecolor','green')
% 
% % Example 6: 
% figure
% h = circles(5,10,3,'edgecolor',[.5 .2 .9])
% 
% % Example 7: 
% lat = repmat((10:-1:1)',1,10); 
% lon = repmat(1:10,10,1); 
% r = .4; 
% figure
% h1 = circles(lon,lat,r,'linewidth',4,'edgecolor','m','facecolor',[.6 .4 .8]);
% hold on;
% h2 = circles(1:.5:10,((1:.5:10).^2)/10,.12,'edgecolor','k','facecolor','none');
% axis equal 
% 
% % Example 8: Circles have corners
% This script approximates circles with 1000 points. If all those points
% are too complex for your Pentium-II, you can reduce the number of points
% used to make each circle.  If 1000 points is not high enough resolution,
% you can increase the number of points.  Or if you'd like to draw
% triangles or squares, or pentagons, you can significantly reduce the
% number of points. Let's try drawing a stop sign: 
% 
% figure
% h = circles(1,1,10,'points',8,'color','red'); 
% axis equal
% % and we see that our stop sign needs to be rotated a little bit, so we'll
% % delete the one we drew and try again: 
% delete(h)
% h = circles(1,1,10,'points',8,'color','red','rot',45/2); 
% text(1,1,'STOP','fontname','helvetica CY',...
%     'horizontalalignment','center','fontsize',140,...
%     'color','w','fontweight','bold')
% 
% figure
% circles([1 3 5],2,1,'points',4,'rot',[0 45 35])
% 
%
% TIPS: 
% 1. Include the name-value pair 'facecolor','none' to draw outlines
% (non-filled) circles. 
% 
% 2. Follow the circles command with axis equal to fix distorted circles. 
%
% See also: fill, patch, and scatter. 

%% Check inputs: 

assert(isnumeric(x),'Input x must be numeric.')
assert(isnumeric(y),'Input y must be numeric.')
assert(isnumeric(r),'Input r must be numeric.')

if ~isscalar(x) && ~isscalar(y)
    assert(numel(x)==numel(y),'If neither x nor y is a scalar, their dimensions must match.')
end
if ~isscalar(x) && ~isscalar(r)
    assert(numel(x)==numel(r),'If neither x nor r is a scalar, their dimensions must match.')
end
if ~isscalar(r) && ~isscalar(y)
    assert(numel(r)==numel(y),'If neither y nor r is a scalar, their dimensions must match.')
end

%% Parse inputs: 

% Define number of points per circle: 
tmp = strcmpi(varargin,'points')|strcmpi(varargin,'NOP')|strcmpi(varargin,'corners')|...
    strncmpi(varargin,'vert',4); 
if any(tmp)
    NOP = varargin{find(tmp)+1}; 
    tmp(find(tmp)+1)=1; 
    varargin = varargin(~tmp); 
else
    NOP = 1000; % 1000 points on periphery by default 
end

% Define rotation
tmp = strncmpi(varargin,'rot',3);
if any(tmp)
    rotation = varargin{find(tmp)+1}; 
    assert(isnumeric(rotation)==1,'Rotation must be numeric.')
    rotation = rotation*pi/180; % converts to radians
    tmp(find(tmp)+1)=1; 
    varargin = varargin(~tmp); 
else
    rotation = 0; % no rotation by default.
end

% Be forgiving if the user enters "color" instead of "facecolor"
tmp = strcmpi(varargin,'color');
if any(tmp)
    varargin{tmp} = 'facecolor'; 
end

%% Begin operations:

% Make inputs column vectors: 
x = x(:); 
y = y(:);
r = r(:); 
rotation = rotation(:); 

% Determine how many circles to plot: 
numcircles = max([length(x) length(y) length(r) length(rotation)]); 

% Create redundant arrays to make the plotting loop easy: 
if length(x)<numcircles
    x(1:numcircles) = x; 
end

if length(y)<numcircles
    y(1:numcircles) = y; 
end

if length(r)<numcircles
    r(1:numcircles) = r; 
end

if length(rotation)<numcircles
    rotation(1:numcircles) = rotation; 
end

% Define an independent variable for drawing circle(s):
t = 2*pi/NOP*(1:NOP); 

% Query original hold state:
holdState = ishold; 
hold on; 

% Preallocate object handle: 
h = NaN(size(x)); 

% Plot circles singly: 
for n = 1:numcircles
    h(n) = fill(x(n)+r(n).*cos(t+rotation(n)), y(n)+r(n).*sin(t+rotation(n)),'',varargin{:});
end

% Return to original hold state: 
if ~holdState
    hold off
end

% Delete object handles if not requested by user: 
if nargout==0 
    clear h 
end

end
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I correct this error? I am rather new to Octave and Matlab, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot call a script as if if were a function. Your `circles.m` file must have a `function` statement as the first non-comment statement.

Comment: I have added what my circles.m looks like.

Comment: If your file looks like that, you wouldn’t be getting an error about “script circles.m”. Did you verify the path given in the error message, that it matches the file you think is being called?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

this is the first post after pasting the error so maybe it'll help anyone later:
in my case pasting the script into  a function worked out!

```
function retval = name_of_script(parametres) 

%your script

endfunction
```